# When the sequence $0\to\Bbb{Z}[G']\to\Bbb{Z}[G]\to\Bbb{Z}[G'']$ is exact given a sequence $G'\to G\to G''$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, exact-sequence

> A group homomorphism $\phi:G'\to G$ gives rise to $\Bbb{Z}$-module homomorphism $\tilde{\phi}:\Bbb{Z}[G']\to\Bbb{Z}[G'']$ defined as $\tilde{\phi}(\sum\limits_{h\in G'} a_h h)=\sum\limits_{h\in G} a_h \phi(h)$. Give conditions under which the sequence $0\to\Bbb{Z}[G']\to\Bbb{Z}[G]\to\Bbb{Z}[G'']$ is short exact for a given sequence $G'\to G\to G''$?

Now we are given a exact sequence $G' \xrightarrow{\phi}G\xrightarrow{\psi}G''$. I can prove that if $\psi$ is injective then $\tilde{\phi}$ is injective and if $\psi$ is surjective then $\tilde{\psi}$ is surjective. I can also prove that $\tilde{\psi}\circ \tilde{\phi}=0$ i.e. $\text{Image}(\tilde{\phi})\subseteq\text{Ker}(\tilde{\psi})$. But I'm unable to prove $\text{Image}(\tilde{\phi})=\text{Ker}(\tilde{\psi})$. Do I need any more condition on the sequence $G'\to G\to G''$?

Comment: I would expect it's almost never exact, except in some trivial cases such as $G' = 0$ or $G'' = 0$.  For example, if $G' = 2\mathbb{Z}$, $G = \mathbb{Z}$, and $G'' = \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$, then $x^3 - x \in \mathbb{Z}[G]$ maps to 0 in $\mathbb{Z}[G'']$ but it is not in the image of $\mathbb{Z}[G']$.

Comment: You can already tell that this can't happen most of the time by a simple counting argument: if $G, G', G''$ are all finite then the exactness of $1 \to G' \to G \to G'' \to 1$ implies $|G| = |G'| |G''|$ but the exactness of $0 \to \mathbb{Z}[G'] \to \mathbb{Z}[G] \to \mathbb{Z}[G''] \to 0$ implies $|G| = |G'| + |G''|$.

Comment: Oh, right, the composition $\mathbb{Z}[G'] \to \mathbb{Z}[G'']$ is a (unital) ring homomorphism and therefore can never be zero (unless the target ring is the zero ring, which $\mathbb{Z}[G'']$ can never be).

Comment: A somewhat related exercise you might want to try: show that if $G' \to G \to G''$ is exact, then the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}[G] \to \mathbb{Z}[G'']$ is generated *as an ideal* of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ by $\{ e_{\phi(g')} - 1 \mid g' \in G' \}$ (actually, make that generated as a left-ideal; it's also true that it's generated as a right-ideal by that set).